# How to restrict access to Firebase onCall functions without authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a website hosted in Firebase Hosting that has a calculation simulator. This is an open website, without any user authentication.

I would like to have an onCall function API that delivers all the simulation parameters to the frontend.

So, should I create this API as public keeping setting permissions to "allUsers"?

Is there a way to restrict this API access only to the Firebase Project? If not, is there a way to do this in the function code?